# jQuery find text and hide that text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide the text from the paragraphs. The problem is that the script find the text and remove the whole paragraph. I want to remove only that text that is searched for.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aanN2/)

```
<div class='article'>    
    <p>Text may refer to: Contents. 1 Computers and electronics; 2 Arts and entertainment; 3 See also. Text (journal), an academic journal of language, discourse, and...</p>
</div>

$(function() {
    var foundin = $('.article p:contains("journal")');
    $(foundin).hide();
});
```

Comment: This is happening as foundin contains the paragraphs that has that word. and foundin will hide that paragraph.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LUzqT/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text in hidden spans with a class

```
$(function() {
    var text = 'journal';
    $('.article p').html(function(_,html) {
        return html.replace(new RegExp('('+text+')','g'), '<span class="hidden" style="display:none">$1</span>')
    });
});
```

to show it again you can do

```
$('.hidden').show();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nM44m/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var foundin = $('.article p:contains("journal")');
foundin.text(foundin.text().replace(/journal/g, ""))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aanN2/5/

Comment: Worth pointing out that only replaces the *first* instance of "journal" in the text, not all of them. Changing the first argument of `replace` to `/journal/g` fixes that.

Comment: You solution has a problem. It would remove all other markup present in the paragraph, such as other spans, links...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('.article p:contains("journal")');
    var html = foundin.html();
    html = html.replace('journal', '<span class="hidden">journal</span>');
    $(foundin).html(html);
});
```

And the CSS

```
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

This way, by changing the `.hidden` style you can highlight the text instead hiding it. This solution won't affect the markup of the rest of the paragraph.

[jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aanN2/2/)

Comment: Glad to have helped. But I would improve it using my solution combined with the RegExp method in @adeneo's answer.

Comment: well yeah, I used that in the end.

Answer (score 1):

- It's better to use html() than text(), because there might me some
  HTML code in paragraph.
- You must use regexp to replace all the
  occurrences in text.
- You should use each, because some other answers won't work if there will be multiple paragraphs with matches

http://jsfiddle.net/aanN2/7/

```
$(function() {
    $('.article p:contains("journal")').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/journal/g, ""))
    });
});
```